# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Why this? What I spouse to use in this case?

```
private void inlineImageCantrol_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ItemsControl ImageToGrid = (ItemsControl)sender;

       ImageSource imgSource = ImageToGrid.ItemsSource; //Error
    }
```

Comment: Hey, you are asking the same question twice. Stay there and get it fixed.

Comment: How about getting a book about WPF? And perhaps one more about C#. That would help a lot...

Comment: @user, it doesn't make sense.  You are running the same question concurrently in two places at the same time.

Comment: @GarryVass Im trying to resolve that error. Ok I understand ImageSource is not the same "ItemsSource" So what im spouse to put in replace ImageSource?

Comment: @GarryVass can you please put a example of what I need to do?

Comment: @user3604503, I would delete the other question.  Or this one.  People may think you're abusing the site otherwise.

Comment: @user3604503, you have two answers below which are correct and I cannot improve upon them.  Please accept one of those answers and move on to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, your `ImageToGrid.ItemsSource` is no `ImageSource`.

This will never be true, since `ItemsSource` is a 'list of', which `ImageSource` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`ItemsSource` is an `object` rather than an `ImageSource` and you're trying to implicitly convert it.

Beyond that, ItemsControl.ItemsSource is an `IEnumerable` representing a collect of data rather than an `ImageSource` so you may need to change your approach altogether.

More information on the `ItemsSource` property can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)